# Nx command modifying project.json in every component when generating libary

Tags: angular, monorepo, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I'm working with an Nx monorepo, and I'm using Nx to generate an angular library with the command `npx nx g  @nrwl/angular:library testapp --directory=myDirectory/directory`. When I run this command, every `project.json` file in every component within the monorepo gets modified. In every `project.json` file, it seems the line `"root": "myDirectory/directory/..." gets removed.` Anyone know why or what to do if I don't want it to happen?

Angular CLI version: 14.0
Nx version: 14.5

Answer (score 0):

`root` should never be inside a `project.json`, as it is set intrinsically when reading the file. The `root` is just `dirname('path/to/project.json')`.

There should have been a migration that removed it from all of them, but if thats not been ran the behavior that you'd experience is that it was stripped when running a generator.